# AWS Cloudwatch calling EC2 service restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I am a total noob in AWS Cloudwatch. We have an existing cloudwatch alarm for app1 and once this alarm is hit... it causes some issues on app2.

The reason was, when this alarm from app1 is sent, this means there are a lot of messages in the redis queue. Indirectly this causes app2 losses connection to the redis server.

A solution is to restart app2 via systemctl or service (via ssh to EC2 instance).

I am thinking if there is a way when AWS cloudwatch alarm is triggered/hit, aside from sending the notification... it will also call a service (systemctl restart or service restart) for app2.

If this is possible, any keyword that I can search to get started.

TIA

Comment: You can do: CW Alarm -> SNS -> Lambda, and lambda will use AWS Run Command to run your `systemctl restart` on the instance.